# Is it possible to exit the RUNNABLE state without having executed a single instruction?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm reading the book [Oracle Certified Professional Java SE 7 Programmer Exams 1Z0-804 and 1Z0-805](http://www.apress.com/9781430247647). One of the question asks the output of this code

```
class ThreadTest {
    public static void main(String []args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t1 = new Thread() {
            public void run() { System.out.print("t1 "); }
        };
        Thread t2 = new Thread() {
            public void run() { System.out.print("t2 "); }
        };
        t1.start();
        t1.sleep(5000);
        t2.start();
        t2.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("main ");
    }
}
```

The book says that it will always output `t1 t2 main` because  [TIMED_WAITING](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#TIMED_WAITING) state can be only reach from [RUNNABLE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#RUNNABLE) state.

But I was thinking that a thread can exit a [RUNNABLE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#RUNNABLE) state without having executed a single instruction.

The doc says:

> A thread in the runnable state is executing in the Java virtual machine but it may be waiting for other resources from the operating system such as processor.

Is the answer of the book correct? And is it possible to exit the [RUNNABLE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#RUNNABLE) state without having executed a single instruction?

Comment: `t1.sleep()` doesn't pause the thread you think it pauses.

Comment: OK, [`sleep()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) is a static method and it pauses the current thread but it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe the book is correct, but for different reasons.

First off let's deal with your question directly.  The only way to change out of RUNNABLE state is by executing an instruction which results in its state changing.  This instruction might call a method (which happens to be synchronized and the thread then waits for a lock in BLOCKED) or return from the `run()` method (causing the thread to become TERMINATED).  But these state changes always happen because the thread has done something to change its own state.

**Edit** - Just to elaberate on this; the method `public void run() {}` contains precisely one instruction: `return`.  The thread must execute the `return` to get from RUNNABLE to TERMINATED.

The book is wrong (sort of).  In "normal cases" 5 seconds is easily long enough to kick off a thread.  But there is nothing synchronizing the threads and so nothing forcing the threads to do things in any particular order.

The the flow is:

1. The main thread kicks off t1.
2. The main thread then goes to sleep for 5 seconds.  *You would hope that 5 seconds is long enough for the OS to start a thread, but there is no guarantee that it will.  If the OS is currently under attack from a [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb) it might not have the resources to start the new thread.*
3. The main thread then kicks off t2.  *If the OS is all clogged up and t1 hasn't started yet, there's no guarantee that t2 will not start (execute some code) first.*
4. The main thread then goes to sleep for 5 seconds.
5. The main thread then prints `"main "`.  Again if the OS is clogged up, this might actually happen before t1 or t2 start.

Never rely on a sequence of multiple threads without using synchronization!

Comment: My understanding is that when the `start` method returns, a new thread will be up and running - the thread start is not asynchronous. The javadoc for `Thread.start()` says: _The result is that two threads are running concurrently: the current thread (which returns from the call to the start method) and the other thread (which executes its run method)._ Hence, if we have a fork bomb, the start call would take a long time (or throw an exception if the process limit is reached), but threads would be started unless an exception is thrown.

Comment: @KErlandsson You're taking the word "concurrently" too literally and implying something which is known to be false. On almost every system "concurrently" means time-sliced. Starting a thread just means adding that thread to the OS's pool running threads. It does not mean that the new child thread has been given its first time slice yet by the OS. Between slices other threads can do any *amount of work or nothing at all*. And you have no control over the start and end of your slice.  Therefore **you can not rely on the sequence of multiple thread's actions without using synchronization.**

Comment: I totally agree with your comment. But I think your answer is confusing when you write e.g. "there's no guarantee that t2 will not start first" when there is a guarantee that t1 is created before t2. But, as you write in the comment, there is no guarantee that t1 executes any code before t2 - totally agreed. Maybe we are just interpreting the word "started" differently.

Comment: Fair point.  English gets messy when talking about multi threading.